# object not find when aggregating in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to use aggregate in R. I found an example code:

```
attach(mtcars)   
agg=aggregate(mtcars, by=list(cyl,vs),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)      
detach(mtcars)
```

This works fine. However when I try to do it using my data:

```
library(stats)  
FileName="Raw.csv"  
Raw=read.csv(FileName,header = TRUE)    
Acc1=aggregate(Raw,by=list(Experiment,SsNum),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get the following error message:
Error in aggregate.data.frame(Raw, by = list(Experiment, SsNum), FUN = mean,      object 'Experiment' not found

I also tries to run:
`Acc2=aggregate(Raw,by=list(Raw$Experiment,Raw$SsNum),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

and I got the following error:
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

The warnings are:
1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

my main question is how the Acc1 is differrent from the online example (that works fine).

thank you very much

Ariel

Comment: IN the first argument, you provided the full dataset, You should subset for the columns needed for `mean`

Comment: To answer your main question: the difference is `attach(..) ... detach()`.
BTW: The use of `attach()` is dangerous.

Comment: To help others replicate your issue, I would suggest updating the post with output of `dput(head(Raw,5))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just compute the `mean` of a `numeric variable` so you have at least to take a subset of the data excluding character variables. Thats were you `ACC1` most likely differ from `mtcars`, because in `mtcars` there are only numeric values in, due to this you do not get a warning in the first line.

So in this line:

```
Acc2=aggregate(Raw,by=list(Raw$Experiment,Raw$SsNum),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

You get a error, because in RAW there appears to be column which are not `numeric`

Supposed you have:

```
set.seed(4)
Experiment <- sample(seq(1:3), 5, replace=TRUE)
SsNum <- sample(1:10, 5, replace=TRUE)
value <- rnorm(5)
df <- data.frame(Experiment, SsNum, value)
```

Then aggregate works as follows:

```
aggregate(value ~Experiment + SsNum, data = df, FUN = mean)
  Experiment SsNum      value
1          3     1  1.7768632
2          2     3  0.6892754
3          1     8 -1.2812466
4          1    10  0.8416977
```

Comment: It is only a warning.

Comment: true but as the warning says `argument is not numeric or logical`I assumed I supposed that this, what would help to avoid the warnings